# null and outofbounds exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, exception, methods, wav

I have a sound class that reads an array of samples. It uses a WavIO class to do this. if `WavIO.read()` returns null, i want it to do nothing. what should i do? not sure if its the set or get method or both. Also, i'm getting these 2 errors:

```
symptom: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Sound.shorten(Sound.java:69)

symptom: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at Sound.lengthen(Sound.java:51)


public class Sound {   
private String fileName;
private double [] samples; 
public Sound(){
    this.samples = new double[0];
}

public Sound(Sound pSound){
    double[] temp;
    temp = new double[pSound.samples.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        temp[i] = pSound.samples[i];
    }
    this.samples = temp;
}

public double[] get(){
    return samples;
}

public void increaseVol(double percent){
    // percent = percent/100.0;
    for(int i = 0; i<samples.length;i++){
        samples[i] = samples[i] * (1.0 + percent);
    }
}

public void reduceVol(double percent){
    //percent = percent/100.0;
    for(int i = 0; i<samples.length;i++){
        samples[i] = samples[i] * (1.0 - percent);
    }
}

public void lengthen(){ 
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];

    for(int i = 0;i<samples.length;i++){
        t[i] = samples[i];
    }
    samples = new double[t.length*2];
    for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
        samples[(2*i)] = t[i];
        samples[(2*i)+1] = t[i];
    } 
}

public void shorten(){
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
        t[i] = samples[i];
    }
    samples = new double[t.length/2];
    if(samples.length % 2 == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i <samples.length;i++){
            samples[i] = t[2*i];
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i <samples.length+1;i++){
            samples[i] = t[(2*i)+1];
        }
    }
}

public void reverse(){
    for(int i = 0; i<samples.length; i++){
        samples[i] = samples[(samples.length)-1-i];
    }
}

public void set(double[] mySamples){
    if (mySamples == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null");
    } else {
        samples = new double[mySamples.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mySamples.length; i++) {
            samples[i] = mySamples[i];
        }
    }
}    

public void wavRead(String fileName){
    this.samples = WavIO.read(fileName);

}

public void wavSave(String fileName){
    WavIO.write(fileName,samples);
}
}
```

Comment: Please mark with comments that both lines

Answer (score 1):

For the second ArrayOutOfBounds exception that you mentioned,

In your `lengthen` method you have this loop:

```
samples = new double[t.length*2];
for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
    samples[(2*i)] = t[i];
    samples[(2*i)+1] = t[i];
}
```

The loop should be:

```
samples = new double[t.length*2];
for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
    samples[i] = t[i/2];
}
```

You've already doubled the length of `samples` but your loop goes by the length of `samples`. Doubling it there will make `i` almost twice the length of samples near the end of your loop.

For your other ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, in your `shorten` method you have:

```
else{
    for(int i = 0; i <samples.length+1;i++){  // remove +1
        samples[i] = t[(2*i)+1];              // remove +1
    }
}
```

In this case, you've halved the size of your `samples` array and you're filling it with elements from your `t` array, taking only every second element. You can remove the +1 because these are causing the code to try to do things that are beyond the length of the array.

```
else{
    for(int i = 0; i <samples.length;i++){    
        samples[i] = t[2*i];                   
    }
}
```

Actually, your whole `shorten` method can be shortened:

```
 public void shorten(){
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < samples.length;i++){
        t[i] = samples[i];
    }
    samples = new double[t.length/2];

    for(int i = 0; i <samples.length;i++){
        samples[i] = t[2*i];
    }
}
```

Comment: well the array should be double the length. so if its ABC it should be AABBCC

Comment: i am not debating that the array should be double the length. I am saying that within the loop, you should not double the value of i when you place elements into `samples`

Comment: im not sure what you mean. I'm still a beginner programmer so i'm not sure whats wrong with the code i had.

Comment: @user3284325 That's okay. I don't mind helping beginners. You are on the right track. The exception that you're having, as I'm sure you've figured out, is because your `samples` array only has so many spots in it, but the code was treating the array like it had more spots. You get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the array is too small for what your code is trying to do.

Comment: If the array is only 10 spots long, the program might try to put something into the 11th spot of the array. This would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`